# Flutter upload list to Google Firestore

Tags: list, firebase, arraylist, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add a list from my flutter test app to my Google Firestore.

This is my method, which adds all the data:

```
void postToFireStore(
{String mediaUrl, String location, String description}) {

var reference = Firestore.instance.collection('insta_posts');

  reference.add({
    "marked_friends": [chipstuete.toString()],
    "username": currentUserModel.username,
    "location": location,
    "likes": {},
    "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
    "description": description,
    "ownerId": googleSignIn.currentUser.id,
    "timestamp": new DateTime.now().toString(),

    }).then((DocumentReference doc) {
    String docId = doc.documentID;
    reference.document(docId).updateData({"postId": docId});
  });
}
```

Everything is working fine, expect the list "marked_friends"...

The list "chipstuete" has multiple strings:

> [Martin Seubert, Lena Hessler, Vivien Jones]

But my Firestore looks like that:

[image]

At the moment the whole list is stored in marked_friends[0]...

What do I need to change, that every entry of my list "chipstuete" is stored in a seperate field of my array "marked_friends" in Firestore?

Best regards!

Comment: Remove `toString()` and the brackets? The firestore api will serialize them for you. `"marked_friends": chipstuete` should work just fine

Comment: That doesnt work, I tried it before. No new Document in Firestore gets created and the console says: "Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'AppProfile'"... Thats why I tried to convert the list items to Strings.

Comment: That is because the automatic serialization only works for core dart types like `int`, `bool` and `List` etc. For custom types you need to serialize them yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the solution.

Like SwiftingDuster said, I needed a new method which serializes it to a List:

```
List<String> toList() {

  chipstuete.forEach((item) {
    newtuete.add(item.toString());
  });

  return newtuete.toList();
}
```

After that I just call toList() in my postToFirestore() Method and add "marked_friends": newtuete. Thats it!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a method in your `AppProfile` class that serializes it to a `List`.

So in your `AppProfile` class:

```
class AppProfile {

  ... // Whatever fields/methods you have

  // Add this method
  List<String> getFriendList() {
    // Somehow implement it so it returns a List<String> based on your fields
    return ['name1','name2','name3'];
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
"marked_friends": chipstuete.getFriendList(),
```

Comment: Thank you! Any Idea on how to implement that? Do you recommand "chipstuete.forEach"?

Comment: I have no idea what your `AppProfile` class contains so I can't really tell you exactly how. It seems like you are just trying to save a friend list, so I imagine you would have a `friends` field containing the names of all the user's friends? If that's the case you can just return that.