# In flutter How to save a list to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a list in flutter which has offset points.

```
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];
```

I am trying to save the list to firebase .

```
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.save),
        onPressed: ()=>Firestore.instance.collection('points').add({"point":_points.toString()}),
```

It is saving to firebase as a string
[image: Firebase collection]

When i try to save as a list

```
floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.save),
        onPressed: ()=>Firestore.instance.collection('points').add({"point":_points.toList()}),
```

It gives the following error

```
Invalid argument: Instance of 'Offset'
```

I need to save it an array instead of a string.How can i get that done

Comment: have you tried just ....add({"point":_points})  . since _points is already a list

Comment: here's someone already answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418433/flutter-upload-list-to-google-firestore

Comment: Yes it gives the same error Instance of offset @shababhsiddique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the answer going through the link provided by @Aldy Yuan

```
List<String> points1=[];
  List<String> toList1() {

    _points.forEach((item) {
      points1.add(item.toString());
    });

    return points1.toList();
  }
```

And then i add toList1  in firestore

```
onPressed: ()=>Firestore.instance.collection('points').add({"point":toList1()}),
```

Answer (score 2):

In a single line:

```
'points': _points.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()
```

Notice that you need to implement `.toJson` in your class, which returns a `Map<String, dynamic>`, common in many flutter/firebase integration guides.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you can't save a list of Objects as a field of a document ( unless each list item as a document ) you can mostly add a list of primitive data types as a field of a doc  `(List<String>, List<int> ... )`
, Offset is an object which is not a valid argument since it's not a primitive and that's why it is throwing your error.